# Nodemailer webpack < 5 used to include polyfills errror

Tags: typescript, nodemailer, webpack-5

I am working on a typescript project where I have to send a mail from the application to the user. I have created my sendEmail() as follows

```
import * as nodemailer from "nodemailer";

const sendEmail = async (email: string, hospitalList: any) => {
  try {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp.gmail.com",
      port: 465, // or the appropriate port for your SMTP server
      secure: true, // set to true if using a secure connection (e.g., TLS)
      auth: {
        user: process.env.SMTP_USERNAME,
        pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD,
      },
    });

    const mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.SMTP_USERNAME,
      to: email,
      subject: "List of Hospital List searched",
      text: `Here is the list of hospitals:\n${hospitalList.join("\n")}`,
    };

    const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log("Email sent:", info.messageId);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error sending Email:", error);
  }
};

export default sendEmail;
```

and the sendEmail function is being called in the share.tsx which has the following code

```
const handleShare = async () => {
    if (email.trim() !== "" && selectedItems.length > 0) {
      const sharedItems = selectedItems
        .map(
          (item) =>
            `${item.name} - ${item.link} - ${item.number} - ${item.email}`
        )
        .join("\n");

      try {
        console.log({email, sharedItems})
        await sendEmail(email, sharedItems);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error sending email:", error);
      }
    }
  }
```

I have even included a config-overrides.js to handle the webpack package as follows

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config.resolve.fallback = {
    url: require.resolve("url"),
    assert: require.resolve("assert"),
    crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
    http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
    https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
    os: require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
    buffer: require.resolve("buffer"),
    stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
  };
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: "process/browser",
      Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
    })
  );

  return config;
};
```

but I am still getting this error

---

...
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\Typescript Tutorials\carefinda\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\dkim'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
- install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
...

---

so how do I go about fixing this error, please I cant seem to figure out where the error is generating from